# How validate content of Input box with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i validate content of a input box? that when a user for example write in that inbox     `http://www.example.com` input box turn it into     `www.example.com` .in other words its valide frist http and if its exist remove it automatically and insert the correct and show the correct in that input-box ?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i want a solution for this can u help me more ?

Comment: i dont want its shows an alaramm i want if the http typed its removed autmaticly plz tell me about that function

Comment: I think you have to invest a bit more time lookin for a solution on your own, I mean the answer to this question can be found on Google pretty easily.

Comment: i searched about this but i dont found that ... if u have good link or a simple solition for this plz give me that link

Comment: javascript regular expression, regular expression matching, regular expression replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one liner:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ $(this).val() === 'http://' && $(this).val(''); });
```

Or:

```
$('#validate').click(function(){ 
  var i = $('input');
  (/http:\/\//).test(i.val()) && i.val(i.val().replace('http://',''));
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain the first one? Looks confusing for me

Comment: oh bro i want to do this without any press key

Comment: sry bro its better but i want http removed but the rest of the sentenc remains

Comment: You'll figure it out eventually. You can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info